# Json array access certain element in PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

From a file upload script I am receiving a string, which I believe is a multidimensional array in json format.

```
$string =

'[{"file":"filename_xyz1.png","index":0},{"file":"filename_xyz2.png","index":1},{"file":"filename_xyz3.png","index":2}]'
```

In PHP I want to put only the values of the elements "file" into a PHP array, resulting in:

```
array("filename_xyz1.png", "filename_xyz2.png", "filename_xyz3.png");
```

Echoing first would also be helpful, so I started with decoding the json:

```
$array_files = json_decode($string);

foreach ($array_files as $key => $filename){
    echo $filename['file'];
}
```

Though unfortunately that last part doesn't work out.

Comment: As you decoded it to an object (check `json_decode()` manual), you probably need `$filename->file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to put only the values of the elements "file" into a PHP array

As you are expecting an array you might use the [assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) param on `json_decode()`:

```
$array_files = json_decode($string, true);
```

This will return an array as result